# Template class as parameter template: MSVC error - error C2977: too many template arguments(C++98)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++98

I need to build my code in MSVC(C++98). I declare a template class with template class parameter. At result I am getting an error during compilation at MSVC: 
error C2977: 'Set': too many template arguments

Gcc builds this code well.

You can try it by yourself:
https://godbolt.org/z/YJXLX7

here you are this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Iterator
{
public:
    virtual int size() = 0;
};

template <template<typename> class TContainer, class TType>
class IteratorCollectionTest
    : public Iterator
{
public:
    virtual int size() { m_collection.size(); }

private:
    TContainer<TType> m_collection;
};


template<typename TItem>
class Set
{
public:
    Set();

    Iterator* createIterator();
    int size();

protected:
    class SetInstance;

private:
    SetInstance*    m_instance;
};

template<typename TItem>
class Set<TItem>::SetInstance
{
public:
    Iterator* createIterator() { return new IteratorCollectionTest<Set, TItem>(); }
    int size() { return  m_vec.size(); }

public:
    std::vector<TItem>  m_vec;
};

template<typename TItem>
Set<TItem>::Set()
    : m_instance(new SetInstance())
{
}

template<typename TItem>
Iterator* Set<TItem>::createIterator()
{
    return m_instance->createIterator();
}

template<typename TItem>
int Set<TItem>::size()
{
    return m_instance->size();
}

int main()
{
    Set<int> m_serr;
    Iterator* iter = m_serr.createIterator();
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class templates have a special member, called the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). Inside the scope of the class template, the template name stands for the *current specialization*. It does not stand for the template.

`new IteratorCollectionTest<Set, TItem>()` appears inside the scope of the class template `Set`. So MSVC assumes the `Set` argument does not refer to the template. It assumes that the name refers to the *specialization*, the type that is `Set<TItem>`. And therefore passes a class name where a template name is expected.

It's the behavior mandated by C++98. And that behavior has since been amended in C++11, where the template name appearing as a template argument does not refer to the injected class name. In C++11 and later mode, GCC would accept the code. But when forcing C++98 mode, [it complains too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a12682b70ed6972f).

The workaround is to qualify the name.

```
Iterator* createIterator() { return new IteratorCollectionTest<::Set, TItem>(); }
```

Since `::Set` is a fully qualified name, it can refer only to the template that is at namespace scope.